When is the abelian groups homomorphism $g \mapsto 2g$ injective?
This is possibly an easy question.
Let $(G,+)$ be a countable abelian group. Under what circumstances is the homomorphism $\phi: G \mapsto 2G:=\{g+g: g\in G\}$, defined by $\phi(g)=g+g$ injective?
I think this holds (exactly) when $G$ is generated by a sequence $(g_n)$ (possibly finite, if the group is finitely generated) where each $g_n$ is either of infinite order or odd (finite) order. Is that correct?
Note: Although I accept the comment about $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying this property, I am interested in countable abelian groups and that's why the generating set is at most countably infinite.
Update and follow-up question: It has been verified in the comments that this hold if and only if there exist elements in $G$ having even order (not necessarily generators). A natural follow-up question is whether we can determine the size of the kernel of $\phi$, i.e. $|\ker{(\phi)}|$, based on the cardinality of such elements and other information about these. For example, say there are $m$-elements of even order, $h_1,...,h_m$. I think that there are then $\ell$-elements $g_1,...,g_{\ell}$ for some $\ell \leq m$ so that for any $1\leq i \leq m$ there is $1\leq j(i) \leq \ell$ such that $h_i \in \langle g_{j(i)} \rangle$. Is it true in this case that $|\ker{(\phi)}|=2^{\ell}$?

$\mathbb{R}$ is not generated by any sequence and yet it satisfies your property.

Also, what do you mean by "surjectivity is obvious"?

@Smiley1000 $\phi$ is by definition surjective: it maps onto $2G$ (which by definition is its image).

It might be less confusing to simply ask "when is $g\to g+g$ injective?", rather than adding a bit of noise with the $G$ versus $2G$ thing... :)

Fair enough, let me edit.

If you allow arbitrary generating sets with the given property instead of at most countable ones then the characterization should hold, yes.

@BenSteffan So the characterisation given above should hold in particular for the case of countable abelian groups?

@User Yes. Give me a second to write up an answer.

It seems to me that the obvious thing to say is that it's injective iff there are no elements of order $2$ (ie if every element has infinite-or-odd order). To me this doesn't seem to be equivalent to just having a generating set consisting of elements of infinite-or-odd order, even in the countable case! For example, $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is generated by $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$, which are both of infinite order. I may be confused here since this seems to contradict @BenSteffan.

In the special case of a finitely generated abelian group, you have the classification theorem that it's isomorphic to some finite direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$; and then, that satisfies your condition if and only if no summand in this representation is of the form $\mathbb{Z} / 2^n \mathbb{Z}$.

@IzaakvanDongen No you are correct, thank you for pointing that out! It does hold if all the generators are of finite order (since the order of a sum of elements divides the order least common multiple of the orders of its summands if they are of finite order), but that example convincingly shows that this reasoning goes out the window when there are elements of infinite order.


A natural follow-up question is whether we can determine the size of the kernel of $\phi$, i.e. $|\ker{(\phi)}|$, based on the cardinality of such elements and other information about these.

Generally, the kernel of multiplication by $n$ on an abelian group $A$ is, more or less by definition, a subgroup called the $n$-torsion subgroup, sometimes denoted
$$A[n] = \{ a \in A : na = 0 \}.$$
It is naturally a module over $\mathbb{Z}/n$, and so in particular if $n$ is a prime $p$ it is naturally an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space. This means that if it's finite, it has cardinality a power $p^k$ of $p$, where $k$ is the dimension of $A[p]$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Furthermore in this case the elements of order $p$ are exactly the nonzero elements of $A[p]$, so there are $p^k - 1$ of them.
An explicit example to work through here is $A = (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^k$, where you'll find that $A[p] \cong C_p^k$ for all primes $p$. It is also possible for $A[p]$ to be infinite, for example if $A = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

For example, say there are $m$-elements of even order, $h_1,...,h_m$. I think that there are then $\ell$-elements $g_1,...,g_{\ell}$ for some $\ell \leq m$ so that for any $1\leq i \leq m$ there is $1\leq j(i) \leq \ell$ such that $h_i \in \langle g_{j(i)} \rangle$. Is it true in this case that $|\ker{(\phi)}|=2^{\ell}$?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. If we're talking about the $2$-torsion subgroup then we're only considering elements of order $2$ so I don't know why you're bringing in elements of even order. The condition you seem to be trying to write down is that $\{ g_i \}$ is a basis of $A[2]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, which would produce that count.

Clarification for the last part; A group $H=\langle h \rangle$ of even order $2k$ has $1$ element of order $2$, namely $kh$, and, of course, $2k-2$ elements of even order other than $2$. I was thinking that in the case of the general countable abelian group described above, if we have finitely many elements of even order, $h_1,…,h_m$ we can extract $\ell$ elements $g_1,…,g_{\ell}$ out of these for which any other $h_i$ will be contained in the cyclic group generated by $g_j$. And then my question was whether $|\ker{(\phi)}|=2^{\ell}$. I hope that makes sense now.

@User: no, there's no reason for this to be true already in a case like $A = C_2^2$. Here there are $3$ elements of order $2$, each of which is contained in a distinct cyclic subgroup, so necessarily $\ell \ge 3$, but $A = A[2]$ has order $4 = 2^2$.
